# Opencart - Handling Fee is not showing on checkout page

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am using 'X-Shipping Pro' for shipping charges handling and added 'handling fee' in the 'order totals' section but Handling Fee is not showing on checkout page.
Opencart version is 2.0.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while, I found 'X-fee' extension which is perfect for my need.